# setInterval: glitch while changing delay through button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing a slideshow of images, using pure javascript, so I need a solution in javascript only.

I have a set of 5 images, and I am hiding and showing images using setInterval.

I have a select list, which is used to change the rate of change of images i.e. the delay in setInterval.

I have almost implemented the slideshow, but I am experiencing a glitch when I change the rate of change of images, and I am unable to find a solution to start the slideshow on page load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
    .item{
        width: 1024px;
        height: auto;
        display: none;
    }
    .active{
        width: 1024px;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="speedo">
        <option value="1">1 sec</option>
        <option value="2">2 sec</option>
        <option value="3">3 sec</option>
        <option value="4">4 sec</option>
        <option value="5">5 sec</option>
    </select>

    <div class="container">
        <img class="item" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/xp4isn.jpg" data-index='0'>
        <img class="item" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/212u39z.jpg" data-index='1'>
        <img class="item" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/63vbc2.jpg" data-index='2'>
        <img class="item" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/wb2iaq.jpg" data-index='3'>
        <img class="item" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/ejvqxe.jpg" data-index='4'>
    </div>

    <script>
        var index=0;
        var elemarray = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
        var speedElement = document.getElementById("speedo");
        window.delay = 1000;

        speedElement.addEventListener('change',function(){
            if(timer) window.clearInterval(timer);
            window.delay = parseInt(this.value)*1000;
            var timer = setInterval("rotate()", window.delay);
        })
        function rotate(){
            console.log(delay);
            index++;
            if(index==5) index = 0;
            for(var i=0, len = elemarray.length; i<len; i++){
                (elemarray[i].getAttribute('data-index')==index)?elemarray[i].setAttribute('class','active') : elemarray[i].setAttribute('class','item');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question 1. How to get rid of the glitch? 
Question 2. How do I kick start the slideshow on page load?

Comment: What's your "glitch"? Please describe your problem exactly

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` with strings, because it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setInterval(rotate, window.delay)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1)** You need to initialize `timer`. You are creating it over and over. That's where your glitch comes from.
**Problem 2)** You need to start your interval.
**Problem 3)** Don't use string functions inside `setInterval`.

```
<select id="speedo">
    <option value="1" class="active">1 sec</option>
    <option value="2">2 sec</option>
    <option value="3">3 sec</option>
    <option value="4">4 sec</option>
    <option value="5">5 sec</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <img class="item" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/xp4isn.jpg" data-index='0'>
    <img class="item" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/212u39z.jpg" data-index='1'>
    <img class="item" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/63vbc2.jpg" data-index='2'>
    <img class="item" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/wb2iaq.jpg" data-index='3'>
    <img class="item" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/ejvqxe.jpg" data-index='4'>
</div>
```

```
var timer = 0;
var index = 0;
var itemElements = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var speedElement = document.getElementById("speedo");
var delay = 1000;

speedElement.addEventListener('change',function() {
    if(timer) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
    delay = parseInt(this.value, 10) * 1000;
    timer = setInterval(rotate, delay);
});

function rotate() {
    var len = itemElements.length;
    index = (index + 1) % len;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if(itemElements[i].getAttribute('data-index') == index) {
            itemElements[i].setAttribute('class','active');
        } else {
            itemElements[i].setAttribute('class','item');
        }
    }
}

timer = setInterval(rotate, delay);
```

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/4RtRV/2

Comment: I got to say, index = (index + 1) % 6; is pretty smart. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @anurag, no problem. Updated my answer to use the item elements length instead of a hardcoded value, also fixed the base index (thought it was 1!)

Answer (score 1):

Your timer variable is declared inside listener scope, you need to put it outside:

```
        var timer ;
        speedElement.addEventListener('change',function(){
            changeTimer(this.value);
        })
        changeTimer(1);
        function changeTimer(val){
            if(timer) window.clearInterval(timer);
            window.delay = parseInt(val)*1000;
            timer = setInterval("rotate()", window.delay);        
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly was my mistake, I declared the timer outside, and voila... it works!! Cheers